# Ruby on Rails 4 belongs_to StrongParams Model self. not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, self, strong-parameters

I have two models Items and ItemImages.

ItemImages belongs_to Items.. and that is working fine.

When I do save/create/update in ItemImages, I want to prefix the file name with 'item_id_'

In controller I have:

```
@im = @current_item.item_images.update(item_image_params)

def item_image_params

  params.require(:items).require(:item).require(:item_images).permit(:item_type, :item_image_caption, :uploaded_picture)

 end
```

In ItemImage.rb I have

def uploaded_picture=(picture_field)

```
      unless (picture_field.blank?)

        begin

    name =  self.item_id.to_s + '_' + File.basename(picture_field.original_filename).gsub(/[^\w._-]/, '')

        directory = './app/assets/images/'  +  self.item_type.to_s

        # create the file path

        path = File.join(directory, name)

        # write the file -- b is for binary

        File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(picture_field.read) }

        self.image_file_name = name

    ....
    rescue

         ....
        end


      end

    end
```

The ItemImage.rb is not finding self.item_id.to_s

Comment: post your `item_image_params`

Comment: I did.  Do you mean my request.post params?

Comment: No what does item_image_params contain in your controller?

Comment: Othname,  please see above code